# Stop Image Capture from opening when a new device is connected

Tags: macos, ios, image-capture

Ok I get how to disable Image Capture from opening for a *specific* device, but I'm an iOS developer and I work with a lot of devices. Is there a way to stop this ruddy app from launching the first time I connect any new device? It's a serious invasion of privacy when I connect someone's phone and immediately see their photos plastered on my screen for the world to see!

Comment: The main answers to this are at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/188212/prevent-photos-app-on-osx-yosemite-from-starting-when-plugging-in-device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution might be to use [Cameras](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/31606/cameras) from Flexibits.

Install this preference pane and set "When you connect new cameras:" to "Do nothing" and it should stop your Mac from automatically opening Image Capture when you connect a new device.

Note that Flexibits don't update it anymore, and don't even offer it on their website but in the limited testing I was able to do it does still seem to work. Also since it isn't updated any longer it's a 32-bit preference pane so you'll get that "To use ... preference pane, System Preferences must quite and reopen." when you open it. However you only need to open it once to set the "When you connect new cameras:" option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it out and will mark this as the answer if it works.

Answer (score 24):

Actually, the best way is:

Once Image Capture is open, click the device in the list, then:
Bottom left corner of the application, small triangle. There: switch it to "no application".

Done

Comment: It's the "once it's open" part I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: do it once - and never see it again :)

Comment: Did any of you even read the question? Geesh.

Comment: this answer doesn't seem to be working anymore on el Cap. Image capture will launch, just not mount the phone...

Comment: I wanted to downvote this because it doesn't answer the question. However, I'm afraid it's impossible to disable the opening of Image Capture for all devices. The only way which seems to work is to set the pref. for every single device or memory card as described here.

Comment: The marked answer actually works quite well. It does require installing third-party software, but is free and I haven't had any issues with it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to open iPhoto, go into iPhoto Preferences and next to `Connecting camera opens:` select `No Application`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The only downside will be that this applies to all devices and if you want to download pictures using Image Capture you will have to open it manually, which can be easily done from Spotlight.

Comment: Alas, I don't have iPhoto, nor do I want it.

Comment: I hear ya.  I don't use it myself.   Used to, but not anymore.  The other option is to disable it per unit on image capture itself.  There's there's a button on the lower left corner of the program.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can also change the permission and remove any access rights on the application package/folder. I used this on iTunes as well to prevent it from starting when pressing play and not having Spotify open.

Its as easy as using chmod from Terminal

```
sudo chmod 000 /Applications/Image\ Capture.app
```

or rightclicking the app, opening the info window, scrolling to the bottom of the view and changing them there.

More info on chmod: http://www.chriswrites.com/how-to-change-file-permissions-using-the-terminal/

Comment: This way you can no longer open the app even with Launcher! :(

Comment: True. But you could use Alfred or create an apple script etc to toggle the setting. Think of it as having the safety on :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work in OS X 10.9.5:

```
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.ImageCapture2 HotPlugActionPath ''
```

Not sure if `-currentHost` is really needed, or if it would also work without it.

What I had also tried, which [seems to work for some](https://superuser.com/a/994159/53547) but didn't for me:

```
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.ImageCapture disableHotPlug -bool YES
```

Maybe it depends on the OS version.

Comment: The currentHost option wasn't required but it now is. It's probably safe to include everywhere it doesn't throw an error when you issue the command.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, deleting the app indeed does work. So it's got that going for it which is nice.

However, I renamed the offending application to "Image Capture.disabled" to fix the problem.

Comment: This 'hack' completely deletes the Image Capture app from the user's computer. Not the best 'answer' by far - more like slash & burn.

Comment: yeah, renaming is a better path.

Answer (score -1):

You could delete Image Capture entirely through the Terminal command

```
sudo rm -rf /Applications/Image\ Capture.app/
```

Comment: While this would indeed stop Image Capture from opening (because it would delete the program), it's often a dangerous course of action to delete system files. This program is a part of the operating system, and deleting it could break other components of the system that expect it to be present.

Comment: @Daniel That's purely speculative. I've used many OSX machines with it deleted and have had no issue (and that's purely experiential).

Comment: That's great. What I'm saying, and yes it's hypothetical, is that any future system update might rely on it being there. I'm glad it hasn't caused you any problems so far.

Comment: In theory system updates could expect it to be present, but in my experience, at least with major version updates they just replace Photos and iTunes even after I've deleted them.  So then I go and delete them again.  No problems so far!

Comment: It's great that you've had no problems so far. However, this doesn't mean that most users won't run into problems with this solution in the future, especially when they might need Image Capture in the future. If you really want to offer this solution, I would recommend something reversible, like `sudo mv '/Applications/Image Capture.app' '/Applications/Image Capture.app.disabled'` or `sudo chmod a-x '/Applications/Image Capture.app/Contents/MacOS/Image Capture'`.

Comment: I backed up before doing this, so I have a copy if there's any trouble, but I've not had any troubles either...

I'll usually run a find walking the directory structure for related com files too... and touch an empty file in Applications with the same name and chmod it 000 to prevent OSX from reinstalling the app, as it has done for me in some cases. Software update in my experience sometimes just reinstalls things you deleted on purpose.