# Why does my Mac (Mavericks) always try to import photos on boot?

Tags: iphone, photos, import

Every time I start up my iMac running Mavericks with my phone or ipad connected, I get this dialog:

> Photos in the Camera Roll of “iOS Device” cannot be imported because the device is locked with a passcode.

Image Capture is set to open no application on connecting an iOS device, iPhoto is also set to not open any application on connecting a camera, and I can't figure out what else would be causing this.

[Prevent Photos app on OSX from launching when plugging in device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/188212/prevent-photos-app-on-osx-from-launching-when-plugging-in-device) is technically a duplicate, however the answers in that question do not do anything for me (neither Image Capture nor iPhoto appear to be the problem).

Why does this happen and how can I make it stop, short of upgrading my OS (which I have technical reasons for not doing)?

Comment: Perhaps iTunes is set to synch photos, and to automatically synch when a device is connected? The "Prevent" checkbox in iTunes > Preferences > Devices should be unchecked, and the synch setup in iTunes should likewise have its "Synch Photos" box unchecked.

Comment: Nope, iTunes was also not related to the issue.  I have since upgraded to Sierra so the problem no longer happens anyway.