# How can I copy or sync iPhone photos to macOS via Thunderbolt from the command line?

Tags: iphone, finder, photos

For a year now `Photos` goes berserk when I connect my iPhone to my Macbook. It launches automatically and goes into an infinite loop of "Preparing to import from ...".

Normally I'd be able to [stop `Photos` from auto-launching](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/188228/7985) if I could get `ImageCapture` to have the focus, but `Photos` continuously steals the focus and it's not possible to disable auto-launch from `ImageCapture`.

[image: Image Capture doesn't get focus]

Luckily, a nice [`defaults` line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/211212/7985) on the command line will solve this issue, but now `Finder` goes into an infinite loop of seeing/not seeing the iPhone, whenever the iPhone is connected via `Lightning`.

How do I stop `Finder` from auto-launching when I connect (via `Lightning`) iPhone to macOS?

More importantly, how can I sync or copy iPhone photos to macOS, still via `Lightning`, from the command line (or any other way than through `Photos` and `ImageCapture`)?

Is there, for example, a "target disk mode" for the iPhone?

Comment: I'd be more inclined to look for the root of the problem than try to band-aid it. Try another cable, another port, another dock. There's something obviously wrong with the existing connection.

Comment: This still asks several things at once ("How do I stop Finder from auto-launching", "how can I sync or copy iPhone photos to macOS, still via Thunderbolt, from the command line", "Is there, for example, a "target disk mode" for the iPhone"). Also, focusing on the actual syncing issue might yield better results than trying to work around them.

Comment: PS: AFAIK you can't connect iPhones via Thunderbolt, but maybe we are missing some detail here.

Comment: If you want to start looking at the core problem: Besides the hardware-related ideas from Tetsujin, did you try to create a new user account on your Mac and sync the photos to that one?

Comment: Duh.. confused Lightning with Thunderbolt... Fixed.. Thanks, Tetsujin & nohillside, experimenting some more. Using another account is particularly useful and I somehow completely missed it. Syncing should work so long as I login with the same AppleID on the new user account (?).

Comment: Indeed a blank install of the OS followed by moving my (music + photos) files is unnecessary. I can create a new account and gradually move all files.

Comment: If it works with a new account, you could also try to remove all relevant preferences etc. in your existing one.